# randomly assign without replacement using numbers

Tags: r, random

I have a data set with 100 rows and I have a string of 4 values (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) I want to randomly assign to the rows.  However, I want to assign `A` to 30 rows, `B` to 20 rows, `C` to 10 rows, and `D` to 40 rows.  How would I go about this?

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1:100))
values <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

One way I have thought of is to generate a randomly ordered list of numbers 1-100 and assign the first 10 `A` and so on, but I imagine there would be a much better way to do it than this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two options. The first one probabilistically assigns values to a column in `df`. This does not guarantee that there will be exactly 30, 20, 10, and 40 each of A,B,C,D, respectively. Rather, in expectation there will be.

```
df$values <- sample(values, nrow(df), FALSE, prob = c(.3,.2,.1.,.4))
```

This second option is probably want you want. It randomly samples rows from the dataframe (essentially shuffling the rows) and uses those as extraction indices (inside `[]`) and then assigns to that shuffled set of rows a vector of values A,B,C,D created using `rep` to ensure exactly 30, 20, 10, and 40 occurrences of each value, respectively.

```
df$values[sample(1:nrow(df), nrow(df), FALSE)] <- rep(values, c(30,20,10,40))
```